# Exe file missing icons/images on Network Drive

Tags: flutter, windows, exe, network-drive

My Flutter app exe file works fine on local PC drives (e.g. on user Desktop and any other local drives). But when I copy this exe file on a Network Drive, no icons and images are shown on the app anymore (while the app still works actually). Every dependencies and dlls are packed in the exe file BTW.

So sounds like when the exe file is executed on the Network Drive, it cannot find the path to assets folder or something, right? But why? And how to fix this? Thx all.